# vector pop_back, erase and clear do not destroy the elements of the vector

Tags: c++, vector

vector pop_back, erase and clear do not destroy the elements of the vector:

```
vector <string> strs;
string text = "sample text";
strs.push_back(text);

strs.pop_back();
// or strs.clear();
// or erase(strs.begin());
cout << "vector size: " << strs.size() << "\n";  // returns "0" 
cout << strs[0]; // still returns "sample text", no error !
getc(stdin);
```

how comes the element isn't invalidated?

Comment: A) it wouldn't compile. B) It is *undefined behaviour* to access vector elements out of range.

Comment: Your code has a bug in it. Fix the bug and the mystery will go away. Your question is a classic example of "My code has a bug in it. Why doesn't it work as I expect it to?" and the answer is always "That's why we fix bugs."

Comment: `strs.pop_back;` should be `strs.pop_back();`.

Answer (score 1):

The element was invalidated. The proof is that you got a result you were unable to predict. If it was valid, you would have been able to accurately predict the result. Because the element was invalidated, the result was entirely unpredictable so, unsurprisingly, you couldn't predict what would happen.